# Can't convert openssl rsa .pem into jks, have NullPointerException

Tags: openssl, rsa, keytool, pem, jks

I need .jks file. I have private_key.pem:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and public_key.pem

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
...
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I tried convert it by

```
cat private_key.pem public_key.pem > combined.pem
openssl pkcs12 -export -in combined.pem -out cert.p12 -nocerts
```

(i write -nocert cause without it i have an error: unable to load certificates)

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore cert.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore cert.jks
```

in the last command, i get error

```
keytool error: java.lang.NullPointerException: invalid null input
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: You have to have a certificate, but you don't. It's that simple. There are many different scenarios for how and when to create the certificate, but your question doesn't have enough detail to figure out how these keys are created and what they're being used for.

Comment: `openssl genrsa -aes256 -out privatekey.pem 2048`, for private key.
`openssl rsa –in privatekey.pem -pubout > publickey.pem`, for pulic